# Looping input till condition is given

Tags: python

I'm a beginner currently working on a small python project. It's a dice game in which there is player 1 and player 2. Players take turns to roll the dice and a game is 10 rounds in total(5 rounds for each player). The player with the highest number of points wins.

I am trying to validate the first input so that when for example, the player enters a number instead of “Higher” or “Lower”, the program should respond with ‘Invalid input, please respond with “Higher” or “Lower”’.

Here's my code so far

```
import random

goAgain = "y"
activePlayer = 1
player1Score = 0
player2Score = 0
maxGuesses = 9
while (goAgain == "y"):
    randNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randNum)
    storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
    while(storedAnswer.strip() != 'higher' or storedAnswer.strip() != 'lower'):
        print('Invalid input, please respond with "Higher" or "Lower"')
        storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
        
    randNum2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randNum2)
    if(storedAnswer.strip() == "lower" and randNum2 < randNum):
        if(activePlayer == 1):
            player1Score+=1
        else:
            player2Score+=1
        print("You Win!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif (storedAnswer.strip() == "lower" and randNum2 > randNum):
        print("You Lose!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif (storedAnswer.strip() == "higher" and randNum2 > randNum):
         if(activePlayer == 1):
            player1Score+=1
         else:
            player2Score+=1
         print("You Win!")
         maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif (storedAnswer.strip() == "higher" and randNum2 < randNum):
        print("You Lose!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif(randNum2 == randNum):
        print("Draw!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        
    print(player1Score)
    print(player2Score)
        
        
    if(activePlayer == 1):
        activePlayer = 2
    else:
        activePlayer = 1
        
    if(maxGuesses == 10):
        if(player1Score > player2Score):
            print("Player 1 wins!")
        elif(player2Score > player1Score):
            print("Player 2 wins!")
        else: 
            print("DRAW!")
        break
    else:
        goAgain = input("Do you want to play again: ")
```

The problem that occurs is that instead it print 'invalid input' regardless of whether the condition is true or not.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your input and your program outputs? Technically you ask for `Higher` (with a capital H), but your condition checks for `higher` (with a lower case h).

Comment: Try `while storedAnswer.strip().lower() not in ["higher", "lower"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value is always not equal one or another value.

```
answer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
while answer.strip() not in ['higher', 'lower']:
    print('Invalid input, please respond with "Higher" or "Lower"')
    answer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that with `and` instead:

```py
storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
while(storedAnswer.strip().lower() != 'higher' and storedAnswer.strip().lower() != 'lower'):
    print('Invalid input, please respond with "Higher" or "Lower"')
    storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ")
```

Remember:

```
no(A) or no(B)  = no(A and B)

no(A) and no(B) = no(A or B)
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not making it lowercase (and you are using `or` instead of a `list`).  This is your code correctly:

```py
import random

goAgain = "y"
activePlayer = 1
player1Score = 0
player2Score = 0
maxGuesses = 9
while goAgain == "y":
    randNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randNum)
    storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ").strip().lower()
    while storedAnswer not in ['higher', 'lower']:
        print('Invalid input, please respond with "Higher" or "Lower"')
        storedAnswer = input("Will you roll higher or lower?: ").strip().lower()
        
    randNum2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(randNum2)
    if storedAnswer == "lower" and randNum2 < randNum:
        if activePlayer == 1:
            player1Score+=1
        else:
            player2Score+=1
        print("You Win!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif storedAnswer == "lower" and randNum2 > randNum:
        print("You Lose!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif storedAnswer == "higher" and randNum2 > randNum:
         if(activePlayer == 1):
            player1Score+=1
         else:
            player2Score+=1
         print("You Win!")
         maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif storedAnswer == "higher" and randNum2 < randNum:
        print("You Lose!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        # print(player1Score)
        # print(player2Score)
    elif randNum2 == randNum:
        print("Draw!")
        maxGuesses+=1
        
    print(player1Score)
    print(player2Score)
        
        
    if(activePlayer == 1):
        activePlayer = 2
    else:
        activePlayer = 1
        
    if maxGuesses == 10:
        if player1Score > player2Score:
            print("Player 1 wins!")
        elif player2Score > player1Score:
            print("Player 2 wins!")
        else: 
            print("DRAW!")
        break
    else:
        goAgain = input("Do you want to play again: ")
```

I remove `()` from the `if` and `while` conditions because they are not needed.

**Some people said that you need to replace `or` with `and`.  Instead of doing that, it is better to use `while storedAnswer not in ["higher", "lower"]`.**

`storedAnswer = input(...).strip().lower()` instead of `storedAnswer = input(...)` so that you don't need to write `storedAnswer.strip()` all of the time.